# Absolute positioned element inside relative positioned element. How to get width and height?

Tags: html, css

I realized that when i put an absolute positioned element into a relative positioned element, the last one doesn't get the first's width and height if i don't set it manually. For an example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .box {
      width: 10vw;
      height: 10vw;
      background-color: yellow;
      border: solid black;
      display: block
    }
    
    .cont {
      position: relative;
      display: block;
    }
    
    .cont>.box {
      position: absolute;
      display: block;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <div class="box">1</div>
  <div class="cont">
    <div class="box">2</div>
  </div>
  <div class="box">3</div>
</body>

</html>
```

In this example all 3 boxes are appear, but the third and second one are overlapping. Is there a way to set the absolute positioned element's parameters to the relative one's, automatically with pure CSS?

Comment: what if you told us what you need at the end ? as i suspect you want to change how CSS works as what you are having is logic and fine

Comment: why are you using `position:absolute` in the `. cont >.box`, because absolute positioned elements are out of flow of the document...?

Comment: What i need is to set the relative positioned element's width and height inherted from the absolute one. And i want to know how it's possible or not.

Comment: `What i need is to set the relative positioned element's width and height inherted from the absolute one.`---> and why ? what the reason ? if you have a specific layout you need to achieve tell us, as you simply want something not possible but am sure you want something that we can easily do with something else

Comment: No...this is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To make the width of one object equal to the width of another object, use the following code.

```
<script>
element.style.width = element.offsetWidth + "px"
<script>
```

This is javascript.